# How do i find how long an object can coast for?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, momentum

I am given the mass of an object (a motorcycle), its velocity, the mass of its wheels, and the radius of the wheels. If the object rolls without slipping, how can I possibly find out how high it can coast up hill? In my problem there is no mention of the angle of the hill. It seems like none of things can go together to figure out how high the motorcycle can coast up a hill.

Comment: Sounds like you need to ignore friction. If so, then what does conservation of energy mean here?

Comment: If you are given the mass and radius of the wheels then presumably you should include the energy of the spinning as well as the energy of the bike moving. But to do that you need to know where on the wheels that mass is locate. You could choose to assume it is all at the rim, or make some other assumption.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conservation of energy.  You can calculate initial energy from the translational kinetic energy and rotational kinetic energy stored in the wheels.  The final energy, when the car comes to a complete stop, will just be the gravitational potential energy, given by $U = mgh$.  This height is independent of the angle of the incline.